# How to retrieve from splash if a list was returned?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Following the example provided in the splash source here: https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/master/splash/examples/render-multiple.lua

In that lua script, a lua table was returned instead of a json object.

How can I return and retrieve an array/list instead of a table/dictionary with lua scripts when using scrapy-splash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using scrapy-splash then decoded result is availble as response.data (see https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#responses). You should do something like this to access PNG data for google.com:

```
import base64
# ...
     def parse_result(self, response):
         img = base64.b64decode(response.data["www.google.com"])
         # ...
```

The linked script returns a `{"<url>": "<base64 png data>"}` mapping, not an array.

If you want to return an array, modify the script to use integer keys and  [treat.as_array](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-libs.html#treat-as-array):

```
treat = require('treat')
function main(splash, args)
  splash.set_viewport_size(800, 600)
  splash.set_user_agent('Splash bot')
  local example_urls = {"www.google.com", "www.bbc.co.uk", "scrapinghub.com"}
  local urls = args.urls or example_urls
  local results = {}
  for i, url in ipairs(urls) do
    local ok, reason = splash:go("http://" .. url)
    if ok then
      splash:wait(0.2)
      results[i] = splash:png()
    end
  end
  return treat.as_array(results)
end
```

then you can access data like this:

```
import base64
# ...
     def parse_result(self, response):
         img = base64.b64decode(response.data[0])
         # ...
```

Comment: thanks for an array method that is indeed what I wanted! However, I went and learned some lua and realized that in the example I linked it returned a lua table which is basically a python dictionary which you can then access with response.data[key]

Comment: What if you are not using scrapy, and data is not an attribute of response?